# upload File/Save via queryString without file upload Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

upload/Saving a File in folder without using file upload Control file path is sent through Query String like below

**JS code**

```
var xmlHttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var URL = "../codePages/codePage1.aspx?imgName=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.08326024943277,74.79841209948063&zoom=21&size=550x450&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true";
xmlHttp1.open("POST", URL, true);
xmlHttp1.send();
xmlHttp1.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp1.status == 200) {
    }
}
```

**C# Code**

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.QueryString["imgName"].ToString());
string location = Server.MapPath("~/saveImages/") + fileName;
Request.Files[0].SaveAs(location);
```

Comment: i am not able to save the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querystring contains pathname to the file not the file contents. You will have to read the file and then save its contents to the location.

Something like:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.QueryString["imgName"].ToString());
string location = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/saveImages/") , fileName);
string readText = File.ReadAllText(Request.QueryString["imgName"].ToString());
File.WriteAllText(location, readText);
```

Please make sure that you do proper error / exception handling by using `File.Exists(path)` or something similar. I have not tested this code but I think this should work.

> Also note that, `Request.Files[0]` contains file data which is uploaded using the file upload control.

### Edit:

You may use something like `WebRequest` to read data from a URL. Something similar to:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://yourUrl");

using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using(var content = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(content)){
    var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: gives an error while assigning readText
(URI formats are not supported. )

Comment: This is just an example. You just need to read that file...may be a simple `WebRequest` would help. You may use any other method or some other override to read data from the source and write it to a file at the required location.

Answer (score 1):

Replace This:

```
Server.MapPath("~/saveImages/") + fileName
```

With This:

```
Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/saveImages/") , fileName);
```